# How do I prevent my bash script (tailing a file) from repeatedly acting on the same line?

Tags: bash

I was working on a script that would keep monitoring login to my server or laptop via ssh.

this was the code that I was working with.

```
slackmessenger() {
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"text":"'"$1"'"}' myapilinkwashere 
## removed it the api link due to slack restriction
}

while true
do
        tail /var/log/auth.log | grep sshd | head -n 1 | while read LREAD
        do
        echo ${LREAD}
        var=$(tail -f /var/log/auth.log | grep sshd | head -n 1)
        slackmessenger "$var"
        done
done
```

The issue I'm facing is that it keeps sending the old logs due to the while loop. can there be a condition that the loop only sends the new entries/updated enter as opposed to sending the old one over and over again. could not think of a condition that would skip the old entries and only shows old one.

Comment: Note the title update -- a question should be focused on the technical problem you encountered, not what kind of program you were writing when you encountered it. Similarly, tags should be included to the extent that they target the question more accurately -- if the problem and its solutions would be identical if you were on Fedora, no reason to tag Ubuntu; if they'd be the same on FreeBSD, no need to tag Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `head -n 1` to extract a line at a time, iterate over the filtered output of `tail -f /var/log/auth.log | grep sshd` and process each line once as it comes through.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- this needs to be a bash script, not a sh script!
case $BASH_VERSION in '') echo "Needs bash, not sh" >&2; exit 1;; esac

while IFS= read -r line; do
  printf '%s\n' "$line"
  slackmessenger "$line"
done < <(tail -f /var/log/auth.log | grep --line-buffered sshd)
```

See [BashFAQ #9](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009) describing why `--line-buffered` is necessary.

---

You could also write this as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in '') echo "Needs bash, not sh" >&2; exit 1;; esac

tail -f /var/log/auth.log |
  grep --line-buffered sshd |
  tee >(xargs -d $'\n' -n 1 slackmessenger)
```